# Update-rc.d equivalent on CentOS

Tags: centos

I'm trying to get rid of a nasty rootkit on a centOS machine, and I need to remove the starttup scripts from various rcX.d files :

The command I'm looking for is an equivalent of the debian:

```
update-rc.d -f DbSecuritySpt remove
```

How do I do that in CentOS ?

Comment: If you think you have a rootkit, *rebuilding* the machine is the best idea. You don't know what you have missed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I agree, but after battling with that thing for a day, including killing it manually every 60seconds until I realized a `while true; kill; sleep 60` would do it for me, it's a personal issue. I'll track down and crush the nasty bug, then, I'll rebuild the server peacefully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the service script from /etc/rc.d/rc?.d with:

```
chkconfig --del DbSecurtiySpt
```

Comment: it says : service DbSecuritySpt does not support chkconfig

Comment: Then it's not a startup script in rc.d as you said in your question.  Maybe it's in rc.local?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `find` to search `/etc` recursively, and remove all instances of `DbSecuritySpt`?

first run find to locate instances of the startup script:

```
find /etc/ -type f -name '* DbSecuritySpt*'
```

Then run find with --delete to remove them:

```
find /etc/ -type f -name '* DbSecuritySpt*' -delete
```